# Python - Searching for a specific element in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a loop:

```
 for x in range(0, len(temp)):
    if temp[val] == char:
        print (" %-9r | %10d | %12s" % (char, frequency, huffmanCode[char]))
        val += 1
```

What it is supposed to do is that char variable should be searched in temp list and if it is found it will be displayed.

For example, if I enter "google" then the output should be:

```
Character | Frequency | Huffman Code
------------------------------------
'g'       |         2 |           0
'o'       |         2 |          11
'o'       |         2 |          11
'g'       |         2 |           0
'l'       |         1 |         101
'e'       |         1 |         100
```

But for some reason it does not display anything. How would I search my whole temp list for characters?

Comment: could you define `temp`? Is it a dictionary or list or ...

Comment: temp is a list @DrBwts basically it contains all characters in a given string including whitespaces and special characters

Comment: Well, I beleive you post isn't clear. You're not using `x`, you haven't explained what `temp` is nor what it contains, you haven't told what `val` is. Also in your 'example', "if you enter 'google'" ... enter google where?

Comment: my mistake. val is just a counter for the specific list position. I replaced it with x already. But it still does not print my desired output. Basically my program asks you to enter a word/phrase which will be turned to a list, which is my temp (temp = list(word)) so if I enter "google" then temp contains [g,o,o,g,l,e] @tglaria

Comment: If you have changed your code, then edit this question!. What is `char` then?

Comment: as the variable name stated it is obviously the character being searched...

Comment: Then you would be looking for only one character per string? Why would you expect to print all characters when entering "google". Why haven't you updated the posted code?

Answer (score 2):

should you be looking for the index of x instead of val? Without seeing your whole code / what those variables mean, it's hard to tell. But if temp[val] doesn't equal char initially, it will never be incremented and therefore the result will never change.

Try this maybe?

```
 for x in range(0, len(temp)):
     if temp[x] == char:
         print (" %-9r | %10d | %12s" % (char, frequency, huffmanCode[char]))
         val += 1
```

Comment: I tried that and entered the word "testing" and this came out http://imgur.com/gA3X4w1. It should be printed based on how the word is spelled... @stackunderflow

Comment: are you presorting your list before iterating over it, perhaps?

try running it with this:

        `temp = list('testing')`

Comment: no @stackunderflow I created another list to make sure but still prints the same and yes that is exactly what I did. I only used the temp variable on that part.

Comment: the logic, in that case doesn't make much sense. If `temp == ['t','e','s','t','i','n','g']` iterating over over the indicies will print them in order. The only thing that could possibly change that (without seeing the rest of your code) would be if you ordered or sorted `temp` somehow. :/

Comment: Check this out, http://imgur.com/65tNctj I printed the contents of the list to make sure :/ @stackunderflow

Comment: that's weird. without seeing more of your code, it is pretty difficult for me to guess what's wrong.

Comment: It's a really long one but I just use temp twice. However I did this, http://imgur.com/GMQ0aIh, and it worked but the problem now is it is printing multiple times depending on the length of the list http://imgur.com/hFeJHaL @stackunderflow

Comment: And oh I created another list arr and transferred the contents of temp there @stackunderflow

Answer (score 1):

You could use the count function from the array object, it will return the number of times the item appears in your list, and if the method returns 0 you could skip the print.
Like this:

```
if temp.count(char) > 0 :
    print (" %-9r | %10d | %12s" % (char, frequency, huffmanCode[char]))
```